# react native todo list with TextInput

Tags: react-native

Is it possible to build a todo list with react native that can

1. add new TexInput with the return key
2. focus the new TextInput when created
3. remove TextInputs with the delete key if the TextInput is empty and focus another input

I have a basic list that can add items and focus them but not remove items.

https://snack.expo.io/@morenoh149/todo-list-textinput-spike

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { TextInput, View } from 'react-native';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  currentTextInput = null

  state = {
    focusedItemId: 0,
    items: [
      { id: 0, text: 'the first item' },
      { id: 1, text: 'the second item' },
    ],
  };

  addListItem = index => {
    let { items } = this.state;

    const prefix = items.slice(0, index + 1);
    const suffix = items.slice(index + 1, items.length);
    const newItem = { id: Date.now(), text: '' };
    let result = prefix.concat([newItem]);
    result = result.concat(suffix);

    this.setState({
      focusedItemId: newItem.id,
      items: result,
    });
  };

  focusTextInput() {
    // focus the current input
    this.currentTextInput.focus();
  }

  componentDidUpdate(_, pState) {
    // if focused input id changed and the current text input was set
    // call the focus function
    if (
      pState.focusedItemId !== this.state.focusedItemId
      && this.currentTextInput
    ) {
      this.focusTextInput();
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { focusedItemId } = this.state;
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center' }}>
        {this.state.items.map((item, idx) => (
          <TextInput
            style={{ borderWidth: 1, borderColor: 'black' }}
            value={item.text}
            ref={item.id === focusedItemId
              ? c => this.currentTextInput = c
              : null}
            autoFocus={item.id === focusedItemId}
            onChangeText={text => {
              const newItems = this.state.items;
              newItems[idx].text = text;
              this.setState({
                items: newItems,
              });
            }}
            onSubmitEditing={event => this.addListItem(idx)}
          />
        ))}
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove items you can add a callback to the onKeyPress and check if it was the Backspace (delete) key and if the text field was empty already. If so, you remove the item from the item list.

```js
onKeyPress={({ nativeEvent: { key: keyValue } }) => {
  if(keyValue === 'Backspace' && !items[idx].text) {
    this.removeListItem(idx)
  }
}}
```

In the removeListItem function you can remove the item at the index and update the selected id to the id previous in the list to focus this one.

```js
removeListItem = index => {
  const { items } = this.state;
  const newItems = items.filter(item => item.id !== items[index].id)
  this.setState({
    focusedItemId: items[index - 1] ? items[index - 1].id : -1,
    items: newItems.length ? newItems : [this.createNewListItem()],
  });
}
```

Please find the full working demo here: https://snack.expo.io/@xiel/todo-list-textinput-spike